# Slice an array out of a Google Charts DataTable object

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a [Google Charts DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable) object and I'd like to access one column as an array. I know that there is the [`getValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getValue) function to access individual fields, but is there also a way to get the entire column?

Answer (score 0):

A simple for-loop can do:

```
var my_slice = []
for (var i=0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++){
    my_slice.push(data.getValue(i, 4));
}
```

`data` is my Google Chart DataTable object and `4` is the ID of the column that I want to access.